# Connecting Switches to Hidden Supply Pins in Proteus ISIS

Tags: pins, proteus, source

I am currently working on a simple circuit involving logic gates in Proteus ISIS from Labcenter. By default, the power pins are hidden. You can access them by right-clicking the component, selecting "Edit properties", and going to "Hidden pins". You can then select the power supply you want to use. However, for this particular circuit I am attempting to put a switch between the power supply and the chip's VDD pin, and another switch between the VSS pin and ground (I know this switch is not necessarily needed, and probably should not even be used, but this is just an experiment). Is there a way to do this? Whenever I add in a different netlist name for VDD and VSS when editing the component properties I get errors saying `No power supply specified for net <my net name> in Power Rail Configuration`.

I am using Proteus 7 Professional. I don't think a schematic would be all that helpful at this point,  but let me know if you need it. Basically I just need switches between VDD and +5V and between VSS and GND.

Comment: I have a feeling the marketing folks at Proteus are running around at top speed trying to think of a different name/acronym for their software right now...

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Design from menu toolbar then choose configure power rails.
2. You will see two textarea unconnected power nets and they have the name of < my net name >
3. first choose from name dropdown menu the right voltage VCC or GND, then highlight < my net name > and last click add, repeat the step 3 if there is more one.
4. click ok then save and every thing is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what logic gate are you using in your project!  First of all you don't need a different netlist, so delete that.  Once you setup the VDD and VSS as you already did.  That is it.
All you need to do is to connect your switch +V pin to the hidden VDD by adding a power terminal, the same goes for the GND pin of the switch, just add/attach a GROUND terminal to it. The Rule here is, any POWER/GROUND terminals are automatically connected to the VDD/VSS of device you are using.  For example, I was facing the same problem working on a MAX232, which ISIS hides its Vcc & Gnd.  I needed to connect Pin 2 (VS+) to a Cap.  1uF then to Vcc.  I just connected pin 2 to the -||- then connected a Power terminal from the TERMINALS pane and all went well.  I do the same with Micro controllers (MCU's) all the time.

I hope this will help.  Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Andy,
Not quite sure I'm following your answer. From the chip's properties you need to select the hidden pins and type in the power source where they are connected. However, as you said, they automatically connect to the power/ground terminals. However, I cannot connect the switch to the chip by adding a power terminal--I receive an error saying "No power supply specified" for that power terminal. Even when I connect it to a battery (through the switch) it does not work. Could you clarify your response?